# Bulk file rename, maintaining timestamps, excluding some

Tags: rename, timestamp

In Ubuntu 18.10 have beeen using mmv to prepend folder names (a date) to file names within multiple folders ('-n' flag here to review results):

```
mmv -n './????-??-??*/*.*' './#1#2#3#4-#5#6-#7#8#9/#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8-#10.#11'
```

which for example converts:

```
./2018-12-11/DSC05287.ARW -> ./2018-12-11/20181211-DSC05287.ARW
```

It also converts:

```
./2018-12-11/20181211-DSC05287.ARW -> ./2018-12-11/20181211-20181211-DSC05287.ARW
```

whilst maintaining the timestamps.

Some files have already been renamed, some have not.

How can I filter the command to exclude files matching a pattern - those which start with an 8-digit number followed by a hyphen?

Or do I need a different approach?

Comment: Could it be as simple as making the leading `DSC` substring explicit? i.e. `mmv -n './????-??-??*/DSC*.*' './#1#2#3#4-#5#6-#7#8#9/#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8-DSC#10.#11'`

Comment: That'd be a possibility except there are a whole range of filenames, so DSC* includes a proportion. But possibly I could do it folder by folder.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of all-in-one renaming utilities, so here's how I would do it using only "standard (GNU) equipment", specifically `bash`, `find` and `mv`.

Assuming you're only interested in files that are one directory level down (so `find -maxdepth 2`), and specifically ignoring files that have already been previously renamed (but doing a sanity check with regex backreferences to avoid making assumptions):

```
find -regextype egrep -maxdepth 2 -type f \! -regex '\./([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}).*/\1\2\3-.+' | while read f; do

  if [[ $f =~ ^(\./([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*)/(.+)$ ]]; then
    # The above regex groups its matches into:
    # ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} = the dir pathname
    # ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} = the date in the dir pathname (remember to strip its dashes)
    # ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} = the file name

    mv -v "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"/"${BASH_REMATCH[2]//-}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"

  fi

done
```

And to fix the ones that have already been incorrectly "double-dated" (again, using backreferences to avoid making unwarranted assumptions):

```
find -regextype egrep -maxdepth 2 -type f -regex '\./([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}).*/\1\2\3-\1\2\3-.+' | while read f; do

  if [[ $f =~ ^(\./.+)/([0-9]{8})-[0-9]{8}-(.+)$ ]]; then
    # The above regex groups its matches into:
    # ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} = the dir pathname
    # ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} = the first date chunk
    # ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} = the filename "tail"

    mv -v "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"

  fi

done
```

### Further Reading:

- [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/): in case you need help with regexes
- [bash(1) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html): search for the `=~` operator, then read up on the special `BASH_REMATCH` array
- [findutils | Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions): details on the surprising variety of regexes supported by GNU `find` and `locate`.